# Choosing a random item from an array list in android - why is my code not working?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a small program that, upon a button press, chooses a random creative medium from an `ArrayList` of `Media` objects.  It's not working. I'm a total beginner in Android and I don't have a clue where I'm going wrong.  Can anyone spot the error in my code?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button2;
        TextView tvRandomMedia;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<Media>();

        Media m1 = new Media("painting");
        Media m2 = new Media("Paper sculpturing");
        Media m3 = new Media("sawing");
        Media m4 = new Media("writing");
        Media m5 = new Media("dance");
        Media m6 = new Media("playing music");
        Media m7 = new Media("Graphic design");
        Media m8 = new Media("photography");

        button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) button2Listener);

        media.add(m1);
        media.add(m2);
        media.add(m3);
        media.add(m4);
        media.add(m5);
        media.add(m6);
        media.add(m7);
        media.add(m8);

        tvRandomMedia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }       

    OnClickListener button2Listener=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doRandomMedia();    
        }

        public void doRandomMedia() {
            int creativity = rnd.nextInt(media.size());
            Media expression = media.get(creativity);
            System.out.print("The media of this week is "+ expression); 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: So what's happening?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What's happening *instead*, or can you describe it better than "not working"?

Comment: Thank you @rick The error message i get when i use the debbuging says:"Dead store to rnd in corn.ay.creativeroulette.MainActivity.onCreate(bundle). Maybe you can make sense of it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have put doRandomMedia() method inside the onClickListener. Try the below code and see if it helps.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity45 extends Activity {

    Button button2;
    TextView tvRandomMedia;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<Media>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Media m1 = new Media("painting");
    Media m2 = new Media("Paper sculpturing");
    Media m3 = new Media("sawing");
    Media m4 = new Media("writing");
    Media m5 = new Media("dance");
    Media m6 = new Media("playing music");
    Media m7 = new Media("Graphic design");
    Media m8 = new Media("photography");

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) button2Listener);

    media.add(m1);
    media.add(m2);
    media.add(m3);
    media.add(m4);
    media.add(m5);
    media.add(m6);
    media.add(m7);
    media.add(m8);

    tvRandomMedia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

OnClickListener button2Listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doRandomMedia();
    }

};

public void doRandomMedia() {
    int creativity = rnd.nextInt(media.size());
    Media expression = media.get(creativity);
    System.out.print("The media of this week is " + expression);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the type of your OnClickListener to `View.OnClickListener`.

Second, `media` is not reachable from your `OnClickListener`.

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
...
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doRandomMedia();
    }

    public void doRandomMedia() {
        int creativity = rnd.nextInt(media.size());
        Media expression = media.get(creativity);
        System.out.print("The media of this week is "+ expression);
    }
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In doRandomMedia() method you try to get information from "media" list that defined in method onCreate(). You should move ArrayList media = new ArrayList(); from method to class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<Media>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
}
```